# Qt test undefined reference to class methods

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qt5, qmake

I'm writing unit tests in qt for a project. In some of my tests cases, I have undefined references errors when I build.
In the .pro file, I have changed  `INCLUDEPATH += ../CardGame` but I don't understand why some other included files don't create errors.
Here is a little example

```cpp
void TestGame::testPlayerName()
{
    Player p{"Com"};
    QVERIFY(p.playerName() == "Com");
}
```

Constructor signature

```cpp
Player(const QString &name);
```

When I run this test, I have the error `` undefined reference to `Player::Player(QString const&)' ``  but I don't understand why an error is thrown. *(I have cleaned, rebuilded and it changed nothing)*.

Here is an example of header element which does not create an error at building

```cpp
void TestGame::testCardLoading()
{
    QSKIP("TEST PASSED");
    auto fullGame{loadFullGame()};
    QVERIFY(fullGame.size() == 52);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your test project build files that declare and define Player class, e.g. player.h and player.cpp? Add those files to HEADERS and SOURCES variables in your test project's pro file.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I added the files to the HEADERS and SOURCES variables.
I thought that adding only the includepath would solve my problem